# How to wrap long lines when SELECTing SQL text columns?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm selecting from a table with long text columns. I'd like to wrap long lines to a maximum line length.

From:

```
SELECT * FROM test;
test_id |                                  text
--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lorem
```

To:

```
test_id |              text
--------+-----------------------------
      1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,+
        | consectetur adipiscing elit+
        | . Mauris lorem
```

Comment: On word boundaries? I don't think that feature is supported.

Comment: @Gaius: Ignoring the word boundaries is ok

Comment: Assume you just want to see the result wrapped? Are you executing the query via commandline tool or pgAdmin or phpPgAdmin?

Comment: @Sandy: psql command line tool

Comment: adjust the size of your terminal window? :D

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you're using the `psql` command line tool, issue this command first:

```
\pset format wrapped
```

It should then wrap long lines to your terminal window like so:

```
test_id |              text
--------+-----------------------------
      1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,.
        |.consectetur adipiscing elit.
        |.. Mauris lorem
```

You can also set the number of columns to wrap to with

```
\pset columns 100
```

and you can change the dots to ellipses with

```
\pset linestyle unicode
```

More info: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html

Comment: I found using `\pset columns 0` after `\pset format wrapped` worked best; it tells psql to detect the screen width to set the column size, and it seems to do so intelligently, where columns with shorter string values get a smaller width.

Answer (score 13):

My answer won't directly answer your question because I don't think psql itself can specifically do this. But, `\x` will turn on expanded output, which will place your values like this:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
id         | 1
longstring | This is a long string of text that will be quite long and most likely be very annoying to read if you are viewing results with more than at most a few columns of data. Words words words words words words lorem ipsum.
```

You can also configure your pager to not wrap lines.

To switch to normal display, just issue the command \x again. [Explanation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS):

```
\x [on|off|auto] toggle expanded output (currently off)
```

Answer (score 3):

With the `Regexp_Replace` function, we can control the exact width of each column separately.  In your example, 27 seems to be the desired column width; so we

```
SELECT Regexp_Replace('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris lorem'
, '(.{27})' , E'\\1\n' , 'g');
```

, obtaining

```
       regexp_replace        
-----------------------------
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,+
  consectetur adipiscing eli+
 t. Mauris lorem
```

---

*How it works:*    We tell `Regexp_Replace` to replace a block of 27 consecutive characters *(*`.{27}`*)*, with **itself** *(*`\1`*)* *plus* a **newline** *(*`\n`*)*; and the global flag *(*`g`*)* says to do that for all such 27-character blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Here is a way to actually make it wrap at spaces:
`regexp_replace( long_text, '(.{10,20}) ', E'\\1\n ', 'g')`.

Comment: I like it!!  Building on that, here is a way to make text wrap at _any_ word boundaries (so it will split `foo:bar` into `foo:` and `bar`, for example); **and** without introducing any extra whitespace:  `Regexp_Replace(long_text, '\y(.{1,27})\y', E'\\1\n', 'g')`